# FreeBSD Jail and SSH - /dev/tty: No such file or directory

Tags: freebsd, jail

When I try to connect through SSH from inside the JAIL I get this error:

```
# ssh test@test.com
...
debug1: read_passphrase: can not open / dev / tty: No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

Outside JAIL everythng is working properly. Any ideas?

Steps to reproduce:

```
# jls
JID  IP Address      Hostname                      Path
1     10.10.3.1       demo.example.com             /jails/demo

# jexec 1 tcsh

(inside jail:)
# ssh test@test.com
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087773/emacs-could-not-open-file-dev-tty

Same issue but with how to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does your jail root have a populated /dev filesystem through a devfs mount?  It looks like it doesn't right now.

**Important note:** You should be able to use devfs rules to limit the devices visible to jailed processes.  In particular, access to raw disk device nodes is a *bad* idea.  The *jail(8)* manpage describes this near the following paragraph:

> It is important that *only* appropriate device nodes in devfs be exposed to a jail; access to disk devices in the jail may permit processes in the jail to *bypass* the jail sandboxing by modifying files outside of the jail.  See *devfs(8)* for information on how to use devfs rules to limit access to entries in the per-jail devfs.  A simple devfs ruleset for jails is available as ruleset #4 in `/etc/defaults/devfs.rules`.

You should be able to mount devfs under `/jails/demo/dev` and apply the recommended jail device rules by running as *root* the following commands:

```
# mkdir /jails/demo/dev
# mount -t devfs devfs /jails/demo/dev
# devfs -m /jails/demo/dev rule -s 4 applyset
```

Of course, you can also write a custom ruleset in `/etc/defaults/devfs.rules`, even a special devfs ruleset that only applies to a specific jail.

For more details see also the manpages for *jail(8)*, *devfs(8)*, and *devfs.rules(5)*.

Answer (score 1):

You may also experience this if you're entered the jail via the jail command. If you start up the jail and SSH into it, you should have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

The devfs filesystem is probably not mounted in your jail. Many things will fail, not just ssh.

To mount a properly-filtered devfs automotically, your best bet is to use rc.conf variables:

> jail_enable=YES
>
> jail_list="JAILNAME"
>
> jail_devfs_enable=YES
>
> jail_JAILNAME_rootdir='/jails/demo'
>
> jail_JAILNAME_hostname="demo"

Then you can stop/stop it using "/etc/rc.d/jail start demo", e